# extract symbols names from PDF drawing

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pdf, image-processing

Dears,

I am trying to write a python code to extract exact symbols from a PDF design drawing.

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHQF8.png)

as you see in the previous drawing, there are many cameras, normally in such drawings, each camera have an ID (asset name) for example "cam-001"

the final objective is to have the script extracting the cameras and it's ID and list them in an excel sheet.

Comment: [this](https://nanonets.com/blog/ocr-with-tesseract/) might be of help

Comment: You can find the cameras using template matching. Where is the ID stated? https://www.google.com/search?q=python+template+matching